# Removing duplicates from a list in Haskell without elem

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to define a function which will remove duplicates from a list. So far I have a working implementation:

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs)   | x `elem` xs   = rmdups xs
                | otherwise     = x : rmdups xs
```

However I'd like to rework this without using `elem`. What would be the best method for this?

I'd like to do this using my own function and not `nub` or `nubBy`.

Comment: Link to [Data.List (nub)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) for when I'm googling it again...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do it without `elem` (or your own re-implementation of it).

However, there is a semantic issue with your implementation. When elements are duplicated you're keeping the *last* one. Personally, I'd expect it to keep the first duplicate item and drop the rest.

```
*Main> rmdups "abacd"
"bacd"
```

The solution is to thread the 'seen' elements through as a state variable.

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates = rdHelper []
    where rdHelper seen [] = seen
          rdHelper seen (x:xs)
              | x `elem` seen = rdHelper seen xs
              | otherwise = rdHelper (seen ++ [x]) xs
```

This is more-or-less how `nub` is implemented in the standard library (read the source [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#nub)). The small difference in `nub`'s implementation ensures that it is [non-strict](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Non-strict_semantics), while `removeDuplicates` above is strict (it consumes the entire list before returning).

Primitive recursion is actually overkill here, if you're not worried about strictness. `removeDuplicates` can be implemented in one line with `foldl`:

```
removeDuplicates2 = foldl (\seen x -> if x `elem` seen
                                      then seen
                                      else seen ++ [x]) []
```

Comment: @BradStevenson These solutions are based on very inefficient operations - both the `elem` function and `(++)` have an `O(n)` complexity on list. Although Haskell's laziness protects the algorithm from executing `(++)` on every cycle, these implementations still fall short quite contrastly as compared to alternative implementations presented in other answers. See [__benchmark results__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16111081/485115).

Comment: I think `removeDuplicates3 = foldr (\x seen -> if x \`elem\` seen then seen else x : seen) []` runs faster than removeDuplicates2, as `(:)` operation is constant.

Answer (score 66):

Both your code and `nub` have `O(N^2)` complexity.

You can improve the complexity to `O(N log N)` and avoid using `elem` by sorting, grouping, and taking only the first element of each group.

Conceptually,

```
rmdups :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
rmdups = map head . group . sort
```

Suppose you start with the list `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]`.  By sorting it, you get, `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`; by grouping that, you get, `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4]]`; finally, by taking the head of each list, you get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The full implementation of the above just involves expanding each function.

Note that this requires the stronger `Ord` constraint on the elements of the list, and also changes their order in the returned list.

Comment: Very nice, but note that this places an `Ord` restriction on the list elements, rather than just `Eq`, and the order is not preserved.

Comment: Good point. Made a note of that and the other change in semantics.

Comment: [`ordNub`](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub) provides a copy-paste-ready, *stable* (order-preserving) variant of @scvalex's suggestion to use `Ord`. It also contains analogues for `\\`, `union` and `intersect`.

Answer (score 44):

Even easier.

```
import Data.Set 
mkUniq :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
mkUniq = toList . fromList
```

Convert the set to a list of elements in *O(n)* time:

> ```
> toList :: Set a -> [a]
> ```

Create a set from a list of elements in *O(n log n)* time:

> ```
> fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
> ```

In python it would be no different.

```
def mkUniq(x): 
   return list(set(x)))
```

Comment: elegant, but I don't think Set preserves the order.

Comment: yes, he didn't mention order preservation in his OP.

Answer (score 28):

Same as @scvalex's solution the following has an `O(n * log n)` complexity and an `Ord` dependency. In difference to it, it preserves the order, keeping the first occurences of items.

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

rmdups :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups = rmdups' Set.empty where
  rmdups' _ [] = []
  rmdups' a (b : c) = if Set.member b a
    then rmdups' a c
    else b : rmdups' (Set.insert b a) c
```

### Benchmark results

[image: benchmark results]

As you can see, the benchmark results prove this solution to be the most effective.
You can find the source of this benchmark [here](https://gist.github.com/nikita-volkov/5451343).

Comment: +1. `Set` is definitely a more efficient data structure for large inputs. I'd like to see where the standard library's `nub` fits into this graph - does laziness have an effect on the performance?

Comment: Heh. I was going to write up and submit a version using `Set` insertion, but you beat me to it. Good show.

Answer (score 4):

**Graham Hutton** has a `rmdups` function on p. 86 of **Programming in Haskell**. It preserves order. It is as follows.

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs) = x : filter (/= x) (rmdups xs)
rmdups "maximum-minimum"
```

> "maxiu-n"

This was bothering me until I saw Hutton's function. Then, I tried, again. There are two versions, The first keeps the last duplicate, the second keeps the first.

```
rmdups ls = [d|(z,d)<- zip [0..] ls, notElem d $ take z ls]
rmdups "maximum-minimum"
```

> "maxiu-n"

If you want to take the first and not the last duplicate elements of the list, as you are trying to do, just change `take` to `drop` in the function and change the enumeration `zip [0..]` to `zip [1..]`.

Answer (score 3):

It is too late to answer this question but I want to share my solution which is original without using `elem` and don't assume `Ord`.

```
rmdups' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
rmdups' [] = []
rmdups' [x] = [x]
rmdups' (x:xs) = x : [ k  | k <- rmdups'(xs), k /=x ]
```

This solution removes duplicates in the end of input, while question implementation deletes in the beginning. For example,

```
rmdups "maximum-minimum"
-- "ax-nium"

rmdups' "maximum-minimum"
-- ""maxiu-n"
```

Also, this code complexity is O(N*K) where N is the length of string and K is the number of unique characters in the string. N >= K thus, it will be O(N^2) in worst-case but this means that there is no repetition in the string and this is unlike since you try to delete duplicates in the string.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to @fp_mora answer that on *page 136* of **Programming in Haskell** there is another slightly different implementation:

```hs
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x : xs) = x : rmdups (filter (/= x) xs)
```

It was easier for me to wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 2):

Using [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2):

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

dedup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
dedup = para pseudoalgebra
    where pseudoalgebra Nil                 = []
          pseudoalgebra (Cons x (past, xs)) = if x `elem` past then xs else x:xs
```

While this is certainly more advanced, I think it is quite elegant and shows off some worthwhile functional programming paradigms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this compress function too.

```
cmprs ::Eq a=>[a] -> [a]
--cmprs [] = [] --not necessary
cmprs (a:as) 
    |length as == 1 = as
    |a == (head as) = cmprs as
    |otherwise = [a]++cmprs as
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dropWhile also works, but remember to sort the list before using this

```
rmdups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs) = x : (rmdups $ dropWhile (\y -> y == x) xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remdups xs = foldr (\y ys -> y:filter (/= y) ys) [] xs
```

this apply the function to the first element and the list cnstructed recursively in the same way.
at the first iteration basically you create a list where you only know the first element, and the rest of the list is constructed in the same way (adding the element to the list), and then is filtered to remove the item that specific cycle is adding.

So every iteration adds an element (call it *X*) to the list and filter the list removing all elements =*X*

Answer (score -1):

...or by using the function union from Data.List applied to itself:

```
import Data.List

unique x = union x x
```

Comment: "Duplicates, and elements of the first list, are removed from the the second list, but if the first list contains duplicates, so will the result.". Cfr [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:union)

Comment: unique x = union [] x would probably be better idea.

Comment: It is slow as hell

Answer (score -1):

```
remove_duplicates (x:xs)
  | xs == []       = [x]
  | x == head (xs) = remove_duplicates xs
  | otherwise      = x : remove_duplicates xs
```

You could try doing this. I've merely replaced 'elem' with my own implementation. It works for me.

Comment: this only works for consecutive duplicates (they have to next to each other).