# Return unique tuples from a list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples of the form `[(A,B),(B,A),(D,C),(E,F),(C,D),(F,E)]`. How do I return a list that is just `[(A,B),(C,D),(E,F)]`? The only solutions I've found are to remove repeated tuples, and the only solutions I can think of are the naive O(n^2) solutions. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: If you can use third-party libraries, there seems to be a "set" data type available: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Set.html

Comment: If you're allowed to sort the list beforehand, it's possible to come up with an `O(n log n)` solution.

Comment: I am allowed to sort this list.

Comment: See the answers to this question asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108714/haskell-removing-duplicates-from-a-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the type of the components of your pairs is in the class `Ord`, you can do it in O(n log n) time:

```
import Data.List (sort, group)

sortPair        :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
sortPair (x, y)
  | x <= y      =  (x, y)
  | otherwise   =  (y, x)

uniques :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
uniques =  map head . group . sort . map sortPair
```

So, if we define

```
data T = A | B | C | D | E | F deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

we have, for your example:

```
> uniques [(A,B),(B,A),(D,C),(E,F),(C,D),(F,E)]
[(A,B),(C,D),(E,F)]
```