# Unique combinations of 4 from a list of tuples in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples that repeats and is in no particular order. heres an example

```
let list = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2)]
```

I want to filter this list and get every unique combination of 4 tuples from the list

I found [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114547/return-unique-tuples-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-haskell) to get a unique list where order doesn't matter and i'm not sure how to adapt it to get a unique set of 4.

with the above list the output there would be 2 unique sets of 4.

```
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)] 
     [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)] 
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]  
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)]  
     [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: What should be the output for that example?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the `(1, 2)` pair at the end. Answering now.

Comment: Though you should also get `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]` as answer (5 answers in total)

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac your right i'll update it

Comment: You still need 2 more.. :P

Comment: There ought to be `5 choose 4 = 5` answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this in the list monad lets you pick out all combinations easily. The `Set.fromList` gives us `(==)` defined on `Set.Set`s which ignore order.

```
import           Data.List ((\\), nub)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

someFours xs = nub $ do
  let xs' = nub xs
  choice1 <- xs'
  choice2 <- xs' \\ [choice1]
  choice3 <- xs' \\ [choice1, choice2]
  choice4 <- xs' \\ [choice1, choice2, choice3]
  return $ Set.fromList [choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4]
```

Comment: `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use

```
let sane = nub list in filter (\x -> length x == 4) $ filterM (const [True, False]) sane
```

The `sane = nub list` is needed to remove duplicates in the original list. The `filterM ...` part get's you all the sets in the powerset of `sane` and from here we only select those with length `4`.

The above is not efficient due to the fact that we generate all elements of the powerset first. Use [J. Abrahamson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037970/371834) if performance is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat efficient and compact solution might be this (assuming I've correctly understood your question):

```
import Data.List (nub)

kSubsets :: (Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
kSubsets k = go k . nub
  where
    go 0 _      = [[]]
    go n []     = []
    go n (x:xs) = map (x:) (go (n-1) xs) ++ go n xs
```