# Taking from a list until encountering a duplicate

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, `takeWhile` allows one to take entries from a (potentially infinite) list until a certain condition does not hold.

However, this condition can't depend on the previous entries of the list.

How can I `take` entries from a (potentially infinite) list until I encounter the first duplicate as outlined in this example?

```
*Main> takeUntilDuplicate [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: It's quadratic, but nice: `foldr (\x r -> x : takeWhile (/= x) r) []`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to go about this is to update a piece of state as you traverse the list, similar to what you'd do in an imperative language.  This requires working with the `State` monad, which might take some studying and playing around to get it if it's your first time, but trust me, this is well worth learning.  Let's start with imports:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
```

The state we're going to keep is the `Set` of elements seen up to that point in the list.  So first, let's write a pair of simple `State` actions to manage the set of seen elements:

```
-- Add an element to the context Set
remember :: Ord a => a -> State (Set a) ()
remember a = modify (Set.insert a)

-- Test if the context set contains an element
haveSeen :: Ord a => a -> State (Set a) Bool
haveSeen a = do seen <- get
                return (a `Set.member` seen)
```

Now we're going to combine these two into an action that checks for duplication:

```
isDuplicate :: Ord a => a -> State (Set a) Bool
isDuplicate a = do seen <- haveSeen a
                   remember a
                   return seen
```

You've mentioned the `takeWhile` function.  We're going to build our solution along similar lines.  This is `takeWhile`'s definition:

```
-- different name to avoid collision
takeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile' _ [] =  []
takeWhile' p (a:as)
    | p a =  a : takeWhile p as
    | otherwise =  []
```

We can modify this function to work with a predicate that has the `Bool` wrapped inside a monad:

```
takeWhileM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
takeWhileM _ [] = return []
takeWhileM p (a:as) = 
    do test <- p a
       if test
       then do rest <- takeWhileM p as
               return (a:rest)
       else return []
```

But the key difference here is that because the test in `takeWhileM` is monadic, we can use our stateful `isDuplicate` from above.  So each time we test an element of the list with `isDuplicate`, we will also record that element in the `Set` that's being threaded through the computation.  So now we can write `takeUntilDuplicate` like this:

```
takeUntilDuplicate :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
takeUntilDuplicate as = evalState (takeUntilDuplicate' as) Set.empty
    where takeUntilDuplicate' :: Ord a => [a] -> State (Set a) [a]
          takeUntilDuplicate' = takeWhileM (fmap not . isDuplicate)
```

Example use (with an infinite list argument):

```
 >>> takeUntilDuplicate (cycle [1..5])
 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And what's neat is that several of these pieces of code could be reused for similar problems.

Comment: I like how easy this way is to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you're dealing with `Ord` instances, you can do it like this. This is essentially the same idea as [Luis Casillas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28756160/1477667), but expressed using a fold instead of `State`. Each of our answers uses a different generally applicable technique. Luis includes an excellent explanation of his; the classic explanation of mine is in "A Tutorial on the Universality and Expressiveness of Fold" by Graham Hutton.

```
import Data.Set (member)
import qualified Data.Set as S

takeUntilDuplicate :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
takeUntilDuplicate xs = foldr go (const []) xs S.empty
  where
    go x cont set
      | x `member` set = []
      | otherwise      = x : cont (S.insert x set)
```

If you are actually dealing with `Int` (or anything that can be converted to an `Int` really quickly), you can improve the performance substantially by using `Data.IntSet` or `Data.HashSet` instead of `Data.Set`.

Answer (score 4):

Your point that `takeWhile` doesn't work because you have no contextual information for the individual elements suggests the following strategy: get it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872133/828361) answer of mine makes reference to the decorate-with-context operation, which I called `picks` (because it shows you all the way to pick one element on which to focus). It's the general decorate-with-its-context operation that we just ought to have for free for every containery thing. For lists, it is

```
picks :: [x] -> [(x, ([x], [x]))] -- [(x-here, ([x-before], [x-after]))]
picks [] = []
picks (x : xs) = (x, ([], xs)) : [(y, (x : ys, zs)) | (y, (ys, zs)) <- picks xs]
```

and it works perfectly well for infinite lists, while we're about it.

Now have a go with

```
takeUntilDuplicate :: Eq x => [x] -> [x]
takeUntilDuplicate = map fst . takeWhile (\ (x, (ys, _)) -> not (elem x ys)) . picks
```

(Curiously, I'm disturbed that the above one-liner is rejected for ambiguity of `Eq` if not given the above type signature. I'm tempted to ask a question about it, here. *Oh, it's the monomorphism restriction. How annoying.*)

**Remark.** It makes a lot of sense to (and I normally would) represent the "elements before" component that `picks` delivers using snoc-lists (lists which grow on the right), the better to preserve sharing and visual left-to-right-ness.

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing what `Comonad` is for? The approach is interesting, but it seems rather inappropriate in this context, since `elem` is horribly inefficient for lists.

Comment: Since you ask about `Comonad`, nearly. Certainly things-in-contexts have comonad structure. Here we don't *redecorate* things-in-contexts, so we're not using much of that structure. And you're right that `elem` is relatively inefficient, especially if you have `Ord` to hand. Meanwhile, "interesting...but inappropriate" is what they'll write on my tombstone. The `picks` operation gives full contextual information, and is thus a handily adaptable component. It's the decorate-with-context design idea I want to get across. If naive contexts are a bottleneck, transform to something more searchable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a modified version of [this duplicate removal function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108856/2597135):

```
takeUntilDuplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeUntilDuplicate = helper []
    where helper seen [] = seen
          helper seen (x:xs)
              | x `elem` seen = seen
              | otherwise = helper (seen ++ [x]) xs
```

Note that `elem` is quite inefficient for large lists. Assuming `a` (the data type inside the list) is an `Ord`type, this function could be improved by using [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Set.html) for membership lookup:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

takeUntilDuplicate' :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
takeUntilDuplicate' = helper Set.empty []
    where helper seenSet seen [] = seen
          helper seenSet seen (x:xs)
              | x `Set.member` seenSet = seen
              | otherwise = helper (Set.insert x seenSet) (seen ++ [x]) xs
```

If you don't care about the order of the results returned, the efficiency of the function can be improved further by returning a `Set`:

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Set (Set)

```
takeUntilDuplicateSet :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
takeUntilDuplicateSet = helper Set.empty
    where helper seenSet [] = seenSet
          helper seenSet (x:xs)
              | x `Set.member` seenSet = seenSet
              | otherwise = helper (Set.insert x seenSet) xs
```

Comment: Sorry for the gratuitous edits; I thought I could make a small change, then realized it would take a bit more, goofed that up, realized the whole idea would confuse the OP, and reverted to the original.

Comment: But on the other hand, you do have a pretty serious efficiency problem even in your `takeUntilDuplicate'`, because `++[x]` is slow. You can fix this using cons accumulation with `reverse` at the end; see my answer for another approach.

Comment: @dfeuer I always appreciate edits that try to improve an answer :-) You are correct about the `++ [x]`. I copied that part from the duplicate removal function. I think it might be more efficient to use `Data.Sequence` `|>` for this task if you're not doing it one of the numerous better ways described in the other answers.

Comment: You might be surprised. Building up a list by consing and then reversing the result is fast enough to beat `Seq` overhead in sufficiently simple applications. The problem with either of those approaches is that they unnecessarily build intermediate structures in memory and only use them later. This tends to be bad for cache utilization and generational GC. This problem inherently has one such (the set). Adding more just makes it worse. The solution is to use laziness, as other answers do, to *operationally* build the list from left to right.