# how do you change the following haskell code into a high order function?

Tags: haskell

Define a function

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

that removes duplicates from a list. For example, `rmdups "ababca"` should return
`"abc"`. The order of the elements in the output list is not important

Here is what I have done so far: 
This works:

```
 rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
 rmdups [] = []
 rmdups (x:xs) = x : rmdups (filter(/= x) xs)
```

This does not work, what am I doing wrong:

```
 rmdups = map head . group . sort
```

Comment: It works for the example you have given. What is an example of it not working?

Comment: No the last line of code does not work. The compiler says group is not in scope.

Comment: Ahh, as baxbaxwalanuksiwe says that is because you are missing an `import`. In future questions, you should include any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16108714/1523776

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
import Data.List (nub)
rmdups = nub
```

But I assume that you're not allowed.

Otherwise, your solution (`rmdups = map head . group . sort`) works for me.

[If the compiler says `group` or `sort` not in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780534/how-do-you-change-the-following-haskell-code-into-a-high-order-function#comment61137668_36780534), just import it from `Data.List`.

PS: I believe you meant "point free style", not "higher order function"

Edit: Thanks [user3217013](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3217013) for pointing [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780534/how-do-you-change-the-following-haskell-code-into-a-high-order-function/36780815#comment61138005_36780815) out.

Comment: You also need `Data.List` for `sort`, for some baffling reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like you said I am not allowed to do that. Is there any other way of solving the question, with the use of high order functions.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to do that ? My solution (which is actually yours) uses the higher order function `map`.

Comment: The tasks says that I only have to declare import Data.List (sort) and nothing else.

Comment: Try writing your own version of `group` then. Or try writing the function another way.